# Trying to access an s3 bucket from my app without a logged in user

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am working on an app using [SST](https://docs.sst.dev/), The app uses the ReactStaticSite that SST supports. The app has the ability to log in as a site admin and manage which PDF is loaded into the react app. The issue is that when a non logged in user tries to access the s3 bucket they get an error:

```
Error: No credentials
   at AWSS3Provider.<anonymous> (AWSS3Provider.ts:370:1)
   at step (index.ts:58:1)
   at Object.next (index.ts:58:1)
   at fulfilled (index.ts:58:1)
```

If I change the config of my Amplify.config Auth property

```
    mandatorySignIn: false
```

I no longer see this error, instead I see a 403 error from the s3 bucket url.

Ideally I don't just want a public bucket, is there a way to have the react app be authorized to get from the s3 bucket using the SST framework?